# How to append my conversion results of pandoc to the file?

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to append my HTML to markdown conversion results of pandoc to .md file. The following command overwrites the existing file instead of appending. Is there any parameter to specify the appending operation?

```
pandoc -f html -t markdown -o output.md
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to append the output of pandoc to the `output.md` file? Use the shell's builtin `>>`:

```
pandoc -f html -t markdown >> output.md
```